# Columndefs not working Datatables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatables

I am trying to work with columndefs to add custom colors to a column. But i started with a simple scenario just to get columndefs to work. But i am unable to do so.

This is my CoffeeScript file.

```
jQuery ->
      $('#clients').dataTable
        columns: [
          targets: [0]
          visible: false
        ]
        sAjaxSource: $('#clients').data('source')
```

I have a ROR application. i am using jquery-datatables-rails gem version: 2.2.3 https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails which installs the latest version of datatables - 1.10.

I am not sure why i am unable to set visibility for column zero to be false.

Comment: have you tried `"columnDefs":[{visible: false, "targets":0}]` or `"columns": [{visible: false}]` as specified in the [Reference Docs](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible)

Comment: I just noticed a syntax error in my comment `visible` should be `"visible"`

Comment: I've already tried columns and columndefs. Did not help. The quotes do not help as well since this is a Coffeescript file.

Comment: the problem is your syntax you are correct the quotes are wrong for coffeescript but you need to fix your syntax for this to work.

Comment: What needs to be corrected with the syntax again ?

Comment: `columns:[targets:[0],visible:false]` is incorrect try `columns:[{visible:false}]` and see if that works

Comment: really interested to know if you got columns and columnDefs working together, I'm seeing a similar problem

Answer (score 6):

The format you originally used is for 'columnDefs', with 'column' you have to specify for all columns see [examples](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible).

However I've always had issues with both formats not working so a workaround is to dynamically hide the column after initializing it using:

```
$('#clients').DataTable().column( 0 ).visible( false )
```

Comment: This is the ONLY option that worked for me. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

As Robbie said in his answer, the options given for columns in your example are actually the options meant for columnDefs. However, it should still work since "visible" is a valid property for both columns and columnDefs. Since column options are index based, the "targets" property is just ignored.

I had issues with column visibility as well until I realized that the stateSave option overrides column visible. Though you don't set stateSave in your example, the only reason I can think of for column visible to not work is having stateSave set to true.

You can override the stateSave logic by using the stateSaveParams callback detailed [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveParams).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a missing comma after targets: [0]

```
columns: [
          targets: [0],
          visible: false
        ]
```